# Добавление своего файла css Prestashop 1.7+

Tags: css, веб-программирование, prestashop

Хочу добавить свой файл css в существующую тему, (не хочу захламлять custom.css) Theme/PixtronPro/assets/css/ , но преста его не видит. В config пробовала добавлять, правда там какой-то id id: custom-lib-style и похоже с этим проблемы, а может и с чем-то другим, увы я не супер специалист... В общем как сделать свой файл видимым для Престы? Все кеши почищены и принудительная перекомпиляция стоят.